# Working in IE 11 - when I entered in 5/1/18 in Angular datepicker it changed the date to 5/1/1918 .Getting wrong year at the end of date

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working in IE - I entered in 5/1/18 inside Angular Material datepicker and it changed the date to 5/1/1918

I have tried to search on Angular Material official site and on Stack Overflow but no specific answer.

When I enter 5/1/19 it should display 5/1/2019 the current year  but displaying 5/1/1919 instead

Comment: Have you added all of the required polyfills (located inside `polyfills.ts`) to support IE 11?

Comment: Yes  In polyfill.ts all these are already present    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';